# Create an Ubuntu Install CD with NO network access required

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, cd-image

I'd like to create an Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS install CD, that will partition a hard drive (I need 4 partitions), and install Ubuntu on 2 of them - a primary and a backup. I want the install to avoid using network connectivity. Haven't been able to find any hints about how to avoid the network conn. Would anyone have some pointers?

Comment: Uhm, for what it's worth, I didn't need a network connection during the installation of Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm quite sure that one is not needed in general. While it's certainly possible to change the default partitioning scheme of the installer I doubt it can be done without alterations to its source code. Therefore I'm closing this question as too broad.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that you want it to fit on a **CD** and not require a network connection. I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that 14.04 LTS install can be bundled in a CD. It's ISO is around 1 GB and most of the CDs cannot go beyond 650-700 MB.

I had an old desktop(2008) which cannot boot from USB or DVD so i burned an [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) into a CD drive that can fit into a CD. Once i installed that then installed Unity/Gnome via apt-get. Later upgraded to Ubuntu Linux into that old desktop via network(as it was having wifi card that i added later).

In your case you can also burn the Ubuntu 12.04 ISO to a CD.

Other alternative is to use net installer - you can somehow get a wifi card for this machine if needed.

I know this is not the exact solution to your situation/problem but some work around based on my past experience.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have mentioned I'm asking about Ubuntu server - without the desktop packages, I think it will fit on a CD.